# startScanning() does not find any device in NativeScript App

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I just started learing NativeScript and I made a simple app where I am trying to scan Bluetooth devices.

I used the **"nativescript-bluetooth"** plugin, but the startScanning() does not find any device(or maybe finds only LE bluetooth devices).

However, I want to find all the available devices.

Do I have smt wrong in my code? Is there any other plugin or way for achieving it?

my **bluetooth-page.component.html** file:

```
<StackLayout>
  <Label text="Bluetooth Connection!!!"></Label>
  <Button text="Check Bluetooth" (tap)="doIsBluetoothEnabled()" class="button button-positive"></Button>
  <Button text="Enable Bluetooth" (tap)="doEnableBluetooth()" class="button button-positive"></Button>
  <Button text="Scan devices" (tap)="doStartScanning()" class="button button-neutral"></Button>
  <Button text="Stop Scanning" (tap)="doStopScanning()" class="button button-danger"></Button>

  <GridLayout rows="*">
    <ListView items="{{ peripherals }}" itemTap="onPeripheralTap" separatorColor="#90c3d4">
      <ng-template>
        <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" class="padded-label">
          <StackLayout class="padded-label-stack">
            <Label horizontalAlignment="right" width="30" text="{{ RSSI }}" class="rssi-label"></Label>
          </StackLayout>
          <StackLayout class="padded-label-stack">
            <Label text="{{ name }}" class="title-label" textWrap="true"></Label>
            <Label text="{{ UUID }}" class="uuid-label" textWrap="true"></Label>
          </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
      </ng-template>
    </ListView>
  </GridLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

my **bluetooh-page.component.ts** file:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

var dialogs = require("tns-core-modules/ui/dialogs");
var bluetooth = require("nativescript-bluetooth");
var observable = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable");
var observableArray = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable-array");

var observablePeripheralArray = new observableArray.ObservableArray();
var peripherals = observablePeripheralArray;

@Component({
  selector: "ns-home-page",
  templateUrl: "./home-page.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./home-page.component.css"],
  moduleId: module.id
})
export class HomePageComponent {
  doIsBluetoothEnabled() {
    bluetooth.isBluetoothEnabled().then(function(enabled) {
      dialogs.alert({
        title: "Bluetooth Enabled: ",
        message: enabled ? "Yes" : "No",
        okButtonText: "OK"
      });
    });
  }

  doEnableBluetooth() {
    bluetooth.enable().then(function(enabled) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        dialogs.alert({
          title: "Enable Bluetooth",
          message: enabled ? "Yes" : "No",
          okButtonText: "OK"
        });
      }, 500);
    });
  }

  // this one uses automatic permission handling
  doStartScanning() {
    // reset the array
    observablePeripheralArray.splice(0, observablePeripheralArray.length);
    bluetooth
      .startScanning({
        serviceUUIDs: [], // pass an empty array to scan for all services
        seconds: 10, // passing in seconds makes the plugin stop scanning after <seconds> seconds
        onDiscovered: function(peripheral) {
          dialogs.alert({
            title: "Error occured!",
            message: peripheral.UUID,
            okButtonText: "OK"
          });
          observablePeripheralArray = peripheral;
        }
      })
      .then(
        function() {
          dialogs.alert({
            title: "Scanning is complete",
            message: "Scanning is complete",
            okButtonText: "OK"
          });
        },
        function(err) {
          dialogs.alert({
            title: "Error occured!",
            message: err,
            okButtonText: "OK"
          });
        }
      );
  }

  doStopScanning() {
    bluetooth.stopScanning().then(
      function() {
        dialogs.alert({
          title: "Stop Scanning",
          message: "Scanning is stopped",
          okButtonText: "OK"
        });
      },
      function(err) {
        dialogs.alert({
          title: "Error occured!",
          message: err,
          okButtonText: "OK"
        });
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the version of Android on your device you are testing with? What is your targeted device, the one that suppose be shown while scanning?

Comment: @Manoj the phone where I run my app is Samsung Galaxy S8 with Android version 9 and I am trying to find Samsung S6 phone via bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the peripheral to the array. You should use TypeScript with strict type checking to ensure simple errors like this don't happen.

```js
onDiscovered: (peripheral: Peripheral) => {
          observablePeripheralArray.push(peripheral);
        }
```

Also, I don't understand why you are alerting "Error occured!" when you discover a new peripheral.

Comment: Hi! Still does not find any device and I also get that error: error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Peripheral'. I added this alert to see if the code inside onDiscovered is executed but it does. Can you provide me more help please?